# Swift Dictionary to Array to populate pickerView

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

I have a dictionary... ["12": "AB", "13": "CD"]

I am trying to use this dictionary to populate a pickerView, So i am attempting to split the dictionary into arrays as only AB, CD need to be displayed in the picker but once selected they need to correspond back to their keys.

I keep getting a Cannot convert value of type 'LazyMapCollection? to expected argument type [_]

```
newArray = Array(arrayLiteral: myDictionary.keys)
```

Ive tried changing the type of array, using NSMutableArray etc but This same error keeps popping up.

If anyone has a better way of using dictionary and pickers, i would be open to suggestions, or if anyone can help me solve this issue.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
newArray = Array(myDictionary.values)
```

Your `newArray` will contain the `"AB"` and `"CD"` strings.

Comment: Definitely better than my answer even though both work

Comment: This still returns the same error as stated above :S

Comment: @jack-of-diamonds, that means there is a problem in the code you didn't post here. These two lines `let myDictionary = ["12": "AB", "13": "CD"]
let newArray = Array(myDictionary.values)` execute perfectly in a playground.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most "Swift" way to do it, but this works:

```
var myArray: [String] = []
let dict =  ["12": "AB", "13": "CD"]
for (key, value) in dict {
    myArray.append(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a typo. If you want AB and CD, shouldn't you get values instead of keys?

```
let newArray = Array(myDictionary.values)
```